# How to set up multiple admin with their own orders?

Tags: magento-1, magento-1.7

In my magento website i have multiple admin system so what i need here is to make such a system in which, when the customer place an order the super-admin can assign it to the sub-admin and these admins can see only those orders in sales orders grid which have assigned to them only.

Is it possible if yes then please reply,

Thanks in advance,

Sarvagya

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in Magento by default, yet the "Sales Reps and Dealers" module does just that - http://amasty.com/sales-reps-and-dealers.html